# How can you compute in your head?

Tags: mathematics

How can you easily compute in your head 84.4084% of 25?

Comment: I don't think either answer currently answers the question on it's own, but combined they do. Both leave out a leap in logic that the other fills.

Comment: Agree. More explanation is needed, so I removed the tick for now.

Comment: There's not really a puzzle here, is there?

Comment: @FIreCase you are almost there. You still haven't explained why division by 4 can be done easily.

Comment: But that's how we learned division in primary school, go from digit to digit...no remainders in this case... "easy to do it"  Is that the "explanation" or am I missing something?

Comment: It’s time to bring this adventure to a close.  This isn’t really a puzzle - it’s “applied” trivia at best, and even then it’s rote mechanical application of a simple principle (and such questions are off topic here).  The answers are almost entirely duplicative of the first one which was posted by JMP, which did a more than adequate job of explaining and applying the simple principle. All the extra ornamentation of subsequent answers hasn’t relevantly improved that first answer.  thesquaregroot made an observation pertaining to why solving is so easy but I’m not sure it needed to be said.

Comment: At this point the superfluous answers are going to be removed as duplicative, and the question itself closed as it probably should have been long ago.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> $21.1021$, because $84.4084\%$ of $25$ equals $25\%$ of $84.4084$.

Comment: It had never occurred to me that you can do that!

Comment: Even having graduated as a math major, it still took me a while to figure out why this was true. It might help others to add in a quick explanation as to why this works, something like rot13(k creprag bs l vf k qvivqrq ol bar uhaqerq gvzrf l, juvpu vf rdhvinyrag gb k gvzrf l qvivqrq ol bar uhaqerq, juvpu vf l creprag bs k) (Obviously with numbers and symbols it would be more clear, but I didn't want to give away the solution in a non-spoiled comment)

Comment: Great and simple. Shame I was too late for it.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that:

> All the non-zero digits in 84.4084 are divisible by 4.

From there you can do the following steps in one go easily:

> Divide 84.4084 by 100 to get the raw decimal form, then multiply by 25 to get the answer (i.e. 84.4084 * 1/100 * 25).  But this is the same as multiplying 84.4084 by 25/100 (= 1/4), which is the same as dividing by 4.  And since all the non-zero digits of 84.4084 are divisible by four, we can trivially compute the answer: 21.1021

Answer (score -2):

Well, not sure if this is easy enough, but

> multiplying 84.4084 by 5 two times is definitely doable in the head (however, I only managed to do that from the second attempt). $84 \cdot 5 = 420$, $844 \cdot 5 = 4220 \implies 84.4084 \cdot 5 = 422.042$. In a similar way we get $422.042 \cdot 5 = 2110.21$. The answer is therefore $21.1021$.